# Como saber si hay error en un validator C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Tengo un formulario en Webforms donde se ingresa un Email.

Tiene dos validadores que funcionan correctamente: RequiredFieldValidator, RegularExpressionValidator.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtEmail" runat="server" MaxLength="100" placeholder="Ingrese Email" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEmail" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="*Ingrese Email." ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revEmail" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtEmail" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="*Formato Email inválido." ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
<br />
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnEnviar" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" OnClick="btnEnviar_Click">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span>&nbsp;Enviar
</asp:LinkButton>
```

El problema es, que el codigo aspx.cs necesito saber si hay o no error. Para continuar con la ejecución.

```
protected void btnEnviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //Capturar Email
    string email = txtEmail.Text;
    //if si no hay error --> ir a funcion
    funcionEmail(string email);
}//btnEnviar_Click
```

Comment: *Si no estoy equivocado* tanto `RequiredFieldValidator` como `RegularExpressionValidator` deberían mostrar un mensaje en pantalla cuando se encuentre el erro y no debería permitir el click al botón, pero, si necesitas validarlo por server / code-behind, revisa [estos](https://forums.asp.net/t/1285442.aspx?regular+expression+validator+for+email+format+code+behind+) [enlaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650303.aspx).

Comment: El form no deberia llamar a la funcion si hay un error en el mismo. Te esta llamando a esa funcion asi tengas errores?

Comment: Si, porque no estoy utilizando un <input type="submit">, si no que un <asp:LinkButton> el botón ejecuta la función a pesar de los validadores.

Comment: utiliza if (Page.IsValid)